# Passport-local times out on create user (Node, Express, Postgres, Knex)

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, knex.js, passport-local

I have an Node/Express API serving data to a Vue frontend, and am now adding Passport for authentication and authorization. I have a createUser function which successfully adds the user, but the function hangs when doing so. I'm sure it's just a stupid thing I've missed, like not calling `next()` (although I did that), and I'd appreciate someone with a clearer head having a look.

//authRoutes.js

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const { createUser } = require('../controllers/authController');

router.route('/auth/register').post(createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

//authController.js

```
'use strict';

const authHelpers = require('../auth/_helpers');
const passport = require('../auth/local');

const handleResponse = (res, code, statusMsg) => {
    res.status(code).json({ status: statusMsg });
};

const createUser = (req, res, next) => {
    // passes correct user and pass
    console.log(req.body);
    return authHelpers
        .createUser(req, res, next)
        .then(() => {
            passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
                if (err) {
                    handleResponse(res, 500, 'error');
                    console.log(info);
                }
                if (user) {
                    handleResponse(res, 200, 'success');
                    console.log(info);
                }
            })(req, res, next);
        })
        .catch(next);
};

module.exports = {
    createUser,
};
```

//auth/_helpers.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const knex = require('../db/connection');

const comparePass = (userPassword, databasePassword) =>
    bcrypt.compareSync(userPassword, databasePassword);

const createUser = req => {
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
    return knex('users')
        .insert({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash,
        })
        .returning('*');
};

module.exports = {
    comparePass,
    createUser,
};
```

EDIT 1:

As per @cantuket's suggestion, logging what createUser is returning yields the user object, which correctly inserts into the DB:

//console.log('res: ', result)

````
{ id: 30,
    email: 'boooya@dubay.com',
    password:
     '$2a$10$WNX.9ur7PlS9ZZvZlJk9Tu9j3lWMjaTlUQ1v7i84dqgHscDupIowW',
    admin: false,
    created_at: 2019-03-01T18:22:53.120Z,
    updated_at: 2019-03-01T18:22:53.120Z,
    last_login: null } 
    ```

EDIT 2:
Thanks to [@cantuket][1] for reminding me to get dirty with console logs, I figured it out by switching 'user' with the returned value (here response), and returning nexts. See below for the fix that worked:
````

const createUser = (req, res, next) => {
    return authHelpers
        .createUser(req, res)
        .then(response => {
            passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.info(info);
                    handleResponse(res, 500, 'error');
                    return next(err);
                }
                if (!response) {
                    console.error(err);
                    console.info(info);
                    handleResponse(res, 500, 'no user');
                    return next(err);
                }
                if (response) {
                    handleResponse(res, 200, 'success');
                    next();
                }
            })(req, res, next);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            console.info(info);
            handleResponse(res, 500, 'error');
            return next(err);
        });
};

```
  [1]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/461693/cantuket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not an Answer:**

First thing I'd do is to check what `createUser() -> knex().insert()` is returning...

```
 .then(result => {
     console.log('createUser:', result)
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
            if (err) {
                handleResponse(res, 500, 'error');
                console.log(info);
            }
            if (user) {
                handleResponse(res, 200, 'success');
                console.log(info);
            }
        })(req, res, next);
    })
    .catch(err=> {
       console.log('err createUser:', err)
       next();
    });
```

Comment: so are neither of these being called `console.log(info); `? Also you may want move them above the `handleResponse()` in case that completes before the `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

i can see that you are authenticating passport instead of the signed-up user. ensure to use passport in your main entry file, app.js like this.

```
    const passport = require('passport')

    app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(User.createStrategy()) 
passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>done(null, user.id)); 
passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>User.findById(id, (err, user)=>done(err,  user)))
                         
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.title = 'Conforti';
    res.locals.success = req.session.success || '';
    delete req.session.success;
    res.locals.error = req.session.error || ''; 
    delete req.session.error;
    res.locals.csrfToken= req.csrfToken(); 
    req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)
    req.session.cookie.maxAge = 3600000
    next();
    });
```

in your controller you should import the user model and authenticate it like this:

```
const User = require('../models/users')
```

this is the postLogin function:

```
postLogin: async (req, res, next)=>{   
   const {username, password} = req.body;
   const {user, error} = await User.authenticate()(username, password);
   if(!user && error) return next(error);
   req.login(user, (err)=>{
     if(err) return next(err);
     req.session.success = `Welcome back, ${user.username}`;
     const redirectUrl = req.session.redirectTo || '/';
     delete req.session.redirectTo;
     res.redirect(redirectUrl);
    
   });
  },
```

this may not be the entire code, but it might help you to spot the error.

you can also check the passport documentation on npmjs.com